# Not able to see any plot on rendering a 3d plotly image

Tags: r, r-plotly

I would like to scatter in 3d a tSNE plot with plotly.

I performed the same kind of plotting in 2d with no problem
This is the function call:

```r
 pl <- plot_ly(tsne_df, x = ~tSNE1, y = ~tSNE2, z = ~tSNE3, color = ~cell_clustering, colors = color_clusters)
    add_markers() %>%
    layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = 'x-tSNE'),
                        yaxis = list(title = 'y-tSNE'),
                        zaxis = list(title = 'z-tSNE')))
```

No error message but I am not able to see the plot. Only when saving as png
This is what I see:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVrAE.jpg)
while this is the downloaded image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6O89g.png)

Comment: Are you visualizing the plot in a browser like Chrome or in the RStudio viewer ? There are some issues with the RStudio viewer. It's better to open in a true browser.

Comment: I am using chrome and also MS edge. Very strange. I know about the problem with the Rstudio viewer but actually the plot I shared came out from the Rstudio viewer, generated through an rMarkdown doc which I am using to test the code I am implementing in my shiny webapp

Comment: Hello everybody. Now it works just fine. I just updated the plotly package